# Query site id from Apex test class

Tags: unit-test, query, code-coverage

I'm looking for more information regarding the getSiteId() method from the Site class.

When I run this query from a test class, I get back null. I have seeAllData set to true, but it's unclear to me why I can't grab this id.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you can set the `Site` context in a test. If you include your code, it may be easier to help you find a workaround.

Comment: This is the query I tried executing:

 Site currentSite = [SELECT Id, GuestUserId FROM Site WHERE Id = :Site.getSiteId()];

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post with any additional detail.